# mat-label' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estoy creando varios `Component` usando `AngularMaterial`.

El problema lo tengo cuando quiero añadir un `mat-select`, al añadirlo dentro de un `mat-form-field` el programa no me funciona. No entiendo porque uno si funciona y el otro no.

¿Alguna idea?

Código:

```
<!-- De este no se queja -->
<mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
    <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="data.name" placeholder="Nombre del juego" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>

<!-- De este SÍ se queja -->
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Prueba</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="data.teamMode">
          <mat-option value="1">Equipos</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="2">Individual</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-dialog-content>
```

En cambio si lo hago así, si funciona. El problema que tengo entonces, es que el `placeholder` no me aparece en la pantalla, ya que creo que `Mat-Select` ya no usa `placeholder` en su nueva versión.

```
<mat-select placeholder="Prueba" [(ngModel)]="data.teamMode">
    <mat-option (click)="teamMode(false)" value="0">Individual</mat-option>
    <mat-option (click)="teamMode(true)" value="1">Equipos</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

ERROR

> 1. If 'mat-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Vi este post en [SOEnglish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873128/mat-label-is-not-a-known-element-error-in-latest-angular-material) pero ya importo el `MatFormFieldMoudle` en ambos lados.

La opción 1 es la que tengo implementada (creo) y no me soluciona.
He intentado actualizar de versión de angular, pero me crea otros problemas en otros modulos...
¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: lo pudiste solucionar ?

Comment: Sí. Use un `placeholder=" "` dentro del `mat-select`